# Word/phrase for taking offense but not showing it

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm looking for a word or a phrase that means taking offense but not actually showing it.

Example:

> *Mary was selfless, affectionate and ______ towards criticism/offense.*

Comment: I don't think there will be a dedicated English adjective that conveys both "offended" ***and*** "outwardly unmoved".

Comment: Neither do I. "...and a stony martyr to criticism." Or a stony-faced martyr...

Comment: [**Stoical**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/stoical) can mean *Enduring pain and hardship without showing one's feelings or complaining.*

Comment: Inspired by fumbleFingers: *Mary was selfless, affectionate and **outwardly impervious** towards criticism/offense.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Difficult. I might use *chary* or *leery* in some contexts, but not all, so this can only be a partial answer.

> chary =
> discreetly cautious: such as
>
> a: hesitant and vigilant about dangers and risks
> ”a government chary of getting involved in foreign entanglements”
>
> b: slow to grant, accept, or expend
> ”a person very chary of compliments”
>
> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chary)

> leery = if you are leery of someone, you do not trust them
>
> [Macmillan dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/leery)